# gettext string in php class method arguments

Tags: php, class, methods, arguments, gettext

I have a challenge here with using gettext strings in class methods arguments. They are not translated. Every other (lets say static) strings are translated without problems and gettext works like charm on them.

Here is an example of non-working translation:

```
$myClass->myMethod(_('string to be translated'));
```

Method definition:

```
public function myMethod (arg1) {
    echo arg1;
}
```

It always showing only translation set on first page load. No matter how many time I switch the language, or refresh he page. I also tried to pass string as a variable. Unfortunately it doesn't work too:

```
$var = _('string to be translated'); 
$myClass->myMethod($var);
```

Thank you for your hints! :)

Answer (score 0):

Is there a translation in your locales-File? Do you only use the System locales or your own files too?

Comment: Thank you for your interest. Yes, strings has been picked for translation into pot file and they are translated in appropriate mo files. I see translation if i switch browser preferred language to one supported by application. It means, translation itself are OK. They are just not changed, when i change language. Only static translations works well.

Comment: But doesn't it mean that in this specific Language is no Translation avalilible if other Languages work?

Comment: Likely, for now, I have only one translation available. And I Am definitely sure, that translation is there. As i mentioned, I AM already able to see translation but I Am not able to switch to another. Any other static text works perfect. I Am able to swich between languages pretty well. I suppose it has something to do with php caching or so. I already restart apache, but it didn't help.

Comment: I think I can't understand the Problem at all - what are you doing and wich Result are you expecting?

Comment: OK I have a site primary in Ennglish lang. I created complete translation to Slovak lang. When i try to switch between languages, static strings marked for translation by _('') are translated pretty well. Unfortunately, strings marked same way and passed to functions as arguments don`t accepting language switch. They stays in translation which was set on first page load. Hope my problem will be a bit more clearer now.

Comment: Okay, if you take these Strings (wich don't work) and make this:
 echo _("my String");

Does ist work?

Comment: Good question. I tested it. Same strings echoed are translated without problems as expected.

Comment: Are you really doing only echo in the Method it self's?

Comment: nPoday. I Am very sorry for wasting your time. I discovered, That i not only echoing the variable, i storing it into the session and then i echoing session variable. Which, of course, stay unchanged even i change language. Many thanks to show me the forest behind the trees. And one more time. Sorry. I will close this issue. Have a nice day.

Comment: No Problem - just happend :)